# Как отобразить запущенные процессы всех пользователей в Forever.js?

Tags: linux, node.js

На сервере запускаются node.js приложения с помощью [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever). 
Допустим я авторизуюсь с одного юзера, а процессы запущены от других, то как мне видеть и контролировать процессы остальных? Проблема в том что я могу видеть запущенные процессы своего пользователя. Это решаемая проблема?